# Including common functions in ExtJS4

Tags: extjs

I have some common functions that I need to reuse through several files in my ExtJS4 application. Here is an example of a few:

https://gist.github.com/e651c32039dfdc60635d

or if you don't want to go to the link:

```
/* This adds a method to String objects that allows you to test
*  whether or not a certain character or string exists in a target
*  string. In raw JS you need to check for .indexOf("test") !== -1
*/
String.prototype.contains = function( it ) { return this.indexOf( it ) !== -1; };
```

How can you create something like a module that these functions can go in and then just be 'required' or imported/loaded into each file rather being so un-DRY and including the functions in each file I need to use it in?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using namespaces.

[here the documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext-method-namespace)

Basically i think you want to do it creating a file let's say "Utils.js" and include it somewhere (or dinamically loaded with extjs [autoload](http://www.sencha.com/blog/countdown-to-ext-js-4-dynamic-loading-and-new-class-system) if you use version 4.x).

Inside that file :

```
Ext.namespace('MyUtil.Array');

MyUtil.Array.doSomething = function(param){

   // method code here
}
```

And then in some other file call it like :

```
MyUtil.Array.doSomething(param);
```

At least i think this it what you are asking. Obviously you can use namespaces to hold a class created with powerful extjs class system (also explained in the second link i have posted).

Comment: My question was more centered around plain javascript since that's what I am writing functions for. The example provided allows you to do:

"Hello".contains('ello');
#=> true

Comment: You can basically do the same in plain javascript with `Myutil = {};` and then declare your methods like `Myutil.mymethod = function(x){//dosomething}`. At least if i have understood what are you searching for.